# simple c++ calculator with sqrt and pow?

Tags: c++, calculator

hi i am kind of beginner to c++ , i wanna write a simple c++ calculator , i wrote this program , i dont know how to add pow and sqrt to this , please help me ,

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;
main()
{
    double num1 , num2 ;
    char op ;
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"type number,operator,number"<<endl;
        cin>>num1>>op>>num2;
        switch(op)
        {
        case '+':
            cout<<"plural is "<<num1+num2<<endl;
            break ;
        case '-':
            cout<<"subtract is "<<num1-num2<<endl;
            break ;
        case '*':
        case 'x':
            cout<<"multiple is "<<num1*num2<<endl;
            break ;
        case '/':
        case '\\':
            cout<<"division is "<<num1/num2<<endl;
            break ;
        default:
            cout<<"operator is illegal"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all what syntax do you want to represent those operations?

Comment: x ^ y for for power. y=0.5 for sqrt.  `pow(x,y)`

Comment: <cmath> includes both pow and sqrt functions

Comment: like a calculator ... one input like 25 and answer shows 5 . pow as well

Comment: Don, that's not even needed, if using C++, they're included in math.h (and maybe in C, can't confirm)

Comment: for power function: pow(num1,num2) and for sqrt function: sqrt(num1)

Comment: @Iam M True, but I mentioned cmath because I've been downvoted in the past for referencing a c-style include for a question in c++

Comment: i know , how should i add pow and sqrt ? how should i write ,

Comment: `cout << "sqrt is " << sqrt(num1);`
and
`cout << num1 << " raised to the power " << num2 << sqrt(num1, num2);`

Comment: Khairul Basar : i can not use this parametr beacause it is not true , cause program need num1 op num 2 for cin

Comment: @mohammadnaseri what do you mean by it is not true ?

Comment: Don Shankin : program need as cin , num1 op num2 , how should i fix this?

Comment: @mohammadnaseri as a beginner, you should not cross-tag C. The modern languages are very different and a "natural" C++ solution will help you learn the language better.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the functions provided in cmath (or math.h, as you've already included):

```
cout << "square root of  " << num1 << ": " << sqrt(num1);
```

...

```
cout << num1 << " raised to the power " << num2 << ": " << pow(num1, num2);
```

Comment: if i add this to my program, when i run program it shows me num1 op num 2 i should use 4sqrt4 for sqrt ...

Comment: I'm not following the "4sqrt4"

Comment: You really don't need num2 for sqrt, so you can simply leave it out. Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: You do need num2. IF you don't usit you will can only compute square root. If you want to be able to calculate any, use pow. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a couple of cases:

```
case 'r':       // For radicals
    cout << pow(num1, 1.0/num2);   // Note that if num2 == 2 this is the same as sqrt.
case 'p':       // For pow
    cout << pow(num1, num2);
```

Remember that:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add two more cases in your `switch`

```
case '^':
cout<<"Power is "<<pow(num1,num2);
break;
```

And

```
case 's': // you can't type in the sqrt symbol directly
cout<<"sqrt of num1:"<<sqrt(num1)<<"\nsqrt of num2:"<<sqrt(num2);
```